# How to ensure the exception "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it"?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, debugging, task-parallel-library

In C# WPF application, if in the following button click event habdler:

```
private void start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  for (int i = 2; i < 20; i++)
  {
    var t = Task.Factory.StartNew
    (() =>
         {
            var result=Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString();
       //this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            textBlock1.Text += "root " + i.ToString() + " " +
            result + Environment.NewLine
       ;//to comment this line if to uncomment th others
       //), null);
          }
     );
  }
}
```

to uncomment the commented lines, i.e. to output to textblock through `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` then it is filled with varying thread IDs.

Though with commented lines, as shown above, the textblock stays blank and there is no exception thrown.

In similar situation using `Parallel.For`

```
private void start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Parallel.For(2, 6, (i) 
     => {
           var result = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString();
           textBlock1.Text += "root " + i.ToString() + " " +
                               result + Environment.NewLine;

         }   );
}
```

the application breaks with exception:

> "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it"

Why isn't it thrown in first case, while using `Task.Factory.StartNew()` ?
Any way to ensure this exception?

Comment: Are you getting varying thread ids with StartNew and the lined still commented?  IT's very unclear the way you've worded it.

Comment: In either case you do not want to update UI controls from another thread whether it's start with StartNew, Parallel.For, or manually.

Comment: Try putting try..catch around the code inside task and put a breakpoint on catch... you will get the answer. The behavior is exactly same in both scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exceptions thrown in tasks are always handled by the Task object itself. The exception is later rethrown when you, e.g., access the Task.Result property. This way the handling of the exception is left to the thread creating the Task. If you run the first code snippet and look at the Output pane, you'll see that there are multiple first-chance InvalidOperationException logged there. The exceptions **are** thrown - the tasks just stash them away for later rethrowing.

`Parallel.For` actually does the same - it stashes away all exceptions occurring within the delegate and then, when the loop is finished, it rethrows all exceptions that occurred in a single `AggregateException`. You'll notice that the debugger breaks in the thread calling `Parallel.For`, not within the delegate passed to it.

To cause the exception in the task to propagate to the calling thread, like `Parallel.For` does, call `Wait/WaitAll` on the tasks.

Comment: That would work, but calling `Wait()` on the UI thread is not a good idea, since it will block the UI.

Comment: @svick: `Parallel.For` in OP also blocks the UI thread until all subranges complete